# html5 and cross-domain upload

Tags: html, cross-domain, plupload

I use plupload with html5. I try to upload file from cross-domain site. File uploaded ( I add header Access-Control-Allow-Origin * for server ), but response from server is empty. How to use upload in this case ? For example In jquery I simple select method jsonp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

plupload also sets a `Content-Type` header, so your server must also respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type` or else the OPTIONS request for CORS will fail.

If you need to debug this, the Web Inspector in Google Chrome does a fairly good job at pointing out which was the cause for your CORS request to fail.

Comment: I have a similar problem but I've got the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type` but the response is still empty with Firefox. Everything is ok with Chrome though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21988085/plupload-crossdomain-upload-200-http-error